# html table selected cell using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have generated a dynamic html table using java script. Now I need to get the css class of the cell clicked by the user.

How am I supposed to do this?

Here is the code:

```
function generateSeatMatrix() {
    var rows = parseInt(document.getElementById('txtRows').value);
    var cols = parseInt(document.getElementById('txtCols').value);
    if (!validateMatrixInput(rows, cols)) {
        // TODO display error message
        return;
    }
    var matrixTable = document.getElementById('tblMatrix');
    if (matrixTable.rows.length > 0) {
        for (var k = matrixTable.rows.length - 1; k >= 0; k--) {
            matrixTable.deleteRow(k);
        }
    }
    for (var i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
        matrixTable.insertRow(i);
        for (var j = 0; j < cols; j++) {
            matrixTable.rows[i].insertCell(j);
            matrixTable.rows[i].cells[j].className = 'matrix-cell';
            matrixTable.rows[i].cells[j].setAttribute('onclick', 'hello()');
        }
    }
}
```

The 'hello()' function is supposed to handle the required logic. Right now, the function is called properly but I have no idea how to get the selected cell css class. Actually, i tried to send the position as declaring the event (using setAttribute), but then an error raised.

Comment: So from the generated HTML table you want to get the class of the td cell clicked?

Comment: Yes, exactly! That's what I want to do

Answer (score 1):

I see you are trying to add a onclick as you built but if you create some jquery like so you can do it. But you would have to have jQuery loaded. Although if you are building this dynamically you may need to use $('document').find('td'). This may not be the solution you are looking for but will get the job done.

```
$('td').on('click', function(){ 
    var myClass = this.className; 
})
```

Tried adding in comment but wouldn't show code view.

Comment: could you please tell me where should this code added? Should it be replaced with the 'setAttribute' line that I wrote?

Comment: Write it outside function generateSeatMatrix() because you do not need to load it as you generate the table.

Comment: I appreciate your kind suggestion of course effective but I have come over it in another way which would be mentioned on my answer, thanks you :)

Answer (score 0):

Here is how easily this could be handled..

```
 matrixTable.rows[i].cells[j].setAttribute('onclick', 'hello(' + i + ',' + j + ')');
```

Well done!

Comment: by this way the selected would be reachable and its class could be modified with ease